# rarfile python пример

Tags: python, python-3.x, rar

подскажите пожалуйста, как создать архив rar, через rarfile, только не скидывайте документацию, можно пожалуйста на примере

Comment: Судя по описанию https://github.com/markokr/rarfile, он может только читать rar, создавать не сможет. А почему нужен именно rar?

Comment: В общем у меня проблема такая, мне нужно файлы и каталоги в папке поместить в rar архив, я пытался сдклать это с помощью patoolib, но он помещает мне полностью папку в архив, а мне так не надо, мне нужно, чтобы именно содержимое папки ушло в архив

Comment: ну раз он может читать архивы, то по идее должен из этой папки их достать и положить рядом с ней, а папку потом удалить.. ну это как костыльный вариант

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример создания архива через [patoolib](https://github.com/wummel/patool).

В архиве будет только содержимое папки:

```
import os

# pip install patool
import patoolib


DIR = "<папку, чье содержимое нужно отправить в архив>"

# Запоминаем текущую активную директорию
prev_cwd = os.getcwd()

# Меняем активную директорию на папку DIR
os.chdir(DIR)

# Получаем содержимое папки DIR
files = os.listdir('.')

# Создаем архив, указывая путь в папку выше с списком файлов DIR
patoolib.create_archive('../' + DIR + '.rar', files)

# Восстанавливаем предыдущую активную директорию
os.chdir(prev_cwd)
```

Comment: Вы бог, спасибо!

Comment: @ИгорьЛещенко, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)